# Schematic Map in GIS Tools?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, schematics

**The Question:**

Is there way to leverage GIS tools to author/edit a **schematic map** where elements' geometries has **canvas-based** coordinates rather than real-world coordinates on Earth?

Perhaps to achieve this, a special Coordinate Reference System (CRS) could be used; one that does "No Projection", one that maps an (X,Y) point directly as-is on a Canvas (instead of on Earth).

**Motivation:**

I'm maintaining a Geo-database feeding a real-world map. I'd like to also maintain, in parallel, a "**schematic map**" where I arbitrarily locate the same elements on a planner canvas. So while each element has a Geometry column with real-world coordinates, it also has another geometry column (point, line...etc) with simple X/Y canvas-based coordinates (not real-world) (similar to vectors in an SVG).

Then it would be of great value if I could view/edit this schematic map in GIS tools (like QGIS).

> Example:
>
> - A **Real-World Map**, in one QGIS project, has layers of features using their typical geometry column in a typical CRS (say WGS 84) - this map is typical, no problems here!
> - A **Schematic Map**, in another QGIS project, has layers of the same features but using another geometry column that is canvas-based (rather than the real-world) coordinates.

Although the essence of GIS is to manage elements located on Earth (real-world coordinates), my special use-case would benefit highly from managing a schematic map in the same environment and with the same tools as a real one.

**Any thoughts?**

*NOTE: I'm not trying to **generate** a schematic map automatically (like ArcGIS' Schematics extension does).*

Comment: You could create a local grid CRS to use in any GIS. That would give you local/canvas based "coordinates" that can be translated to real world as they are define as a CRS. We use these for local mine grids defined by affine transformation, where things are measured verry locally. This approach is only really good for local not regional, due to precision errors.